# Call entire User Information List from REST api

Tags: rest

I'm using a REST api to get data from the User Information List using

```
    https://servername/sitename/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items
```

This works great but the list stops after 121 entries - ending with a line such as

```
    <link rel="next" href="https://servername/sitename/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d2102" />
```

How should I go about calling the entire list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some options to do this:

1. Use `Listdata.svc`:
   `http://SiteURL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList`.
   This returns all the items.
2. Use `$top=5000`:
   `http://SiteURL/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items?$top=5000`. This will return all items within the threshold limit.
3. Use `GetItems`
   This is a **POST** request where you can use an empty CAML query to return all the items. Please note that JSON format is default for this and it won't return in XML.
   Request would be like below:
   **URL:** 
   `http://SiteURL/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/getitems`
   **Headers:**
   `Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
    X-RequestDigest: RequestDigest 
    Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose`

   **CAML query:** 
   `{ "query" :
          {"__metadata": 
             {"type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
             , "ViewXml": "<View><Query></Query></View>"
          }
    }`

Comment: Using `getbytitle()` isn't a sure thing here because the list can be renamed (and possibly has different default names in other localities).

Comment: @JLRishe you can use the endpoint http://siteURL/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/items then

Answer (score 0):

header must be included

```
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json
```